# WebBrowser events are not fired when IE is not opened as admin on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, com, bho

After registering BHO on machine with Win7 i realized that something is wrong. When IE is **not opened** as administrator then **OnBeforeNavigate2** and **OnDocumentComplete** events of WebBrowser are not fired. When I run IE as administrator these methods are fired correctly. I subscribing to these metods the following way:

```
    public int SetSite(object site)
    {
        if (site != null)
        {
            webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);

        }
        else
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser.BeforeNavigate2 -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.OnBeforeNavigate2);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

UAC function is turned on with default value.
On machine with Windows XP everything was OK(even on limited account).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the BHO is registered properly on the limited account?

Comment: It is visible on IE addons list so I think that it is installed properly